# Fandol fonts does not contain requested, but I have already install it

Tags: fonts, xecjk

I used `Ubuntu 18.04` in `WSL2`.

Editor is `Vscode 1.44.0`, with plugin `LaTeX Workshop 8.8.0`

TeX Distributions is `Texlive 2020`

My .tex file is like this

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\title{一个标题}
\author{syc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

hello, world

你好，世界

\end{document}
```

The log file I've got

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.4.13)  14 APR 2020 08:51
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**/mnt/c/Users/songy/Desktop/tample/HBUThesis/test
(/mnt/c/Users/songy/Desktop/tample/HBUThesis/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-04-06> (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo
File: bk12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@chapter=\count164
\c@section=\count165
\c@subsection=\count166
\c@subsubsection=\count167
\c@paragraph=\count168
\c@subparagraph=\count169
\c@figure=\count170
\c@table=\count171
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
) (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-04-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count172
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count173
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count174
))
Package: xeCJK 2020/02/18 v3.8.2 Typesetting CJK scripts with XeLaTeX
 (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2020-03-06 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
) (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty
Package: xtemplate 2020-03-06 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
\l__xtemplate_tmp_dim=\dimen135
\l__xtemplate_tmp_int=\count175
\l__xtemplate_tmp_muskip=\muskip16
\l__xtemplate_tmp_skip=\skip49
) (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2020-03-06 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count176
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count177
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count178
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count179
)
\l__xeCJK_tmp_int=\count180
\l__xeCJK_tmp_box=\box46
\l__xeCJK_tmp_dim=\dimen136
\l__xeCJK_tmp_skip=\skip50
\g__xeCJK_space_factor_int=\count181
\l__xeCJK_begin_int=\count182
\l__xeCJK_end_int=\count183
\c__xeCJK_CJK_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass1
\c__xeCJK_FullLeft_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass2
\c__xeCJK_FullRight_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass3
\c__xeCJK_HalfLeft_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass4
\c__xeCJK_HalfRight_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass5
\c__xeCJK_NormalSpace_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass6
\c__xeCJK_CM_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass7
\c__xeCJK_HangulJamo_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass8
\l__xeCJK_last_skip=\skip51
\g__xeCJK_node_int=\count184
\c__xeCJK_CJK_node_dim=\dimen137
\c__xeCJK_CJK-space_node_dim=\dimen138
\c__xeCJK_default_node_dim=\dimen139
\c__xeCJK_default-space_node_dim=\dimen140
\c__xeCJK_CJK-widow_node_dim=\dimen141
\c__xeCJK_normalspace_node_dim=\dimen142
\l__xeCJK_ccglue_skip=\skip52
\l__xeCJK_ecglue_skip=\skip53
\l__xeCJK_punct_kern_skip=\skip54
\l__xeCJK_last_penalty_int=\count185
\l__xeCJK_last_bound_dim=\dimen143
\l__xeCJK_last_kern_dim=\dimen144
\l__xeCJK_widow_penalty_int=\count186

Package xtemplate Info: Declaring object type 'xeCJK/punctuation' taking 0
(xtemplate)             argument(s) on line 2302.

\l__xeCJK_fixed_punct_width_dim=\dimen145
\l__xeCJK_mixed_punct_width_dim=\dimen146
\l__xeCJK_middle_punct_width_dim=\dimen147
\l__xeCJK_fixed_margin_width_dim=\dimen148
\l__xeCJK_mixed_margin_width_dim=\dimen149
\l__xeCJK_middle_margin_width_dim=\dimen150
\l__xeCJK_bound_punct_width_dim=\dimen151
\l__xeCJK_bound_margin_width_dim=\dimen152
\l__xeCJK_margin_minimum_dim=\dimen153
\l__xeCJK_kerning_total_width_dim=\dimen154
\l__xeCJK_same_align_margin_dim=\dimen155
\l__xeCJK_different_align_margin_dim=\dimen156
\l__xeCJK_kerning_margin_width_dim=\dimen157
\l__xeCJK_kerning_margin_minimum_dim=\dimen158
\l__xeCJK_bound_dim=\dimen159
\l__xeCJK_reverse_bound_dim=\dimen160
\l__xeCJK_margin_dim=\dimen161
\l__xeCJK_minimum_bound_dim=\dimen162
\l__xeCJK_kerning_margin_dim=\dimen163
\g__xeCJK_family_int=\count187
\l__xeCJK_fam_int=\count188
\g__xeCJK_fam_allocation_int=\count189
\l__xeCJK_verb_case_int=\count190
\l__xeCJK_verb_exspace_skip=\skip55
 (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count191
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count192
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count193
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen164
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen165
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen166
 (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
) (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg
File: xeCJK.cfg 2020/02/18 v3.8.2 Configuration file for xeCJK package
))

Package xeCJK Warning: Fandol is being set as the default font for CJK text.
(xeCJK)                Please make sure it has been properly installed.


Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolSong-Regular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "CJK".


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FandolSong-Regular(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'FandolSong-Regular' with options
(fontspec)             [Script={CJK},Extension={.otf},BoldFont={FandolSong-Bold},ItalicFont={FandolKai-Regular}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[FandolSong-Regular.otf]/OT:language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[FandolSong-Bold.otf]/OT:language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[FandolKai-Regular.otf]/OT:language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 

(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5.
 (/home/syc/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <14.4> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 6.
 [1


] [2] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4571 strings out of 481357
 143488 string characters out of 5927161
 433007 words of memory out of 5000000
 21989 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 533363 words of font info for 41 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,6n,73p,326b,241s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test.pdf (2 pages).
```

And I already installed fandol fonts

```
~/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fandol
❯ la
total 34M
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc  26K Jul 19  2015 FandolBraille-Display.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc  13K Jul 19  2015 FandolBraille-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc 6.7M Jul 19  2015 FandolFang-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc 3.5M Jul 19  2015 FandolHei-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc 5.6M Jul 19  2015 FandolHei-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc 7.5M Jul 19  2015 FandolKai-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc 5.6M Jul 19  2015 FandolSong-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 syc syc 4.8M Jul 19  2015 FandolSong-Regular.otf
```

Even I put them in the font floders

```
❯ fc-list | grep fandol
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolFang-Regular.otf: FandolFang,FandolFang R:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolBraille-Display.otf: Fandol Braille,Fandol Braille Display:style=Display,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolBraille-Regular.otf: Fandol Braille,Fandol Braille Regular:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolSong-Bold.otf: FandolSong:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolKai-Regular.otf: FandolKai:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolHei-Bold.otf: FandolHei:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolSong-Regular.otf: FandolSong:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/fandol/FandolHei-Regular.otf: FandolHei:style=Regular
```

How to solve these Warning?

Comment: This warning is known; it's safe and can be ignored: https://github.com/CTeX-org/forum/issues/34

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thanks

Comment: You can load the font with `Script=Default` to suppress the warning. `\defaultfontfeatures[FandolSong]{Script=Default}` before `XeCJK` (or `ctex`) might do it.

Answer (score 1):

I find a workaround way

change
`\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}` into
`\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fontset=windows]{ctexbook}`, and remove `\usepackage{xeCJK}`.

Then add Windows sim* fonts into Linux.

Although, it's safe to ignore, I still don't want to see it XD.

Comment: This essentially just replaces the font "Fandol Song" by "SimSun" (and it also replaces the other default fonts for sans serif and monospaced). So, you could also just have added `\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}` to your original code example which would also remove the warning.